# Use Amazon Web Service SDK Client S3 in javascript vanilla

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, node-modules

I want to use aws-sdk/client-s3 in javascript vanilla, without node or npm.

I have found the way to do it in version 2 (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/getting-started-browser.html). But in the latest version (version 3) I can only import it as a module (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/clients/client-s3/index.html#aws-sdkclient-s3)

Is there any way to use client_s3 in vanilla javascript? Without using 'import' or 'require'. Only a script tag.

Comment: As specified in the AWS JS Dev Guide, the setup instructions do require use of npm and import. See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v3/developer-guide/installing-jssdk.html. What is your issue with this  technique?

Comment: Do you think it's impossible to do it in vanilla javascript? Using unpkg.com for example.